# Addition of GROUP BY to simple query makes it 1000 slower

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using test DB from https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db. It has a moderate size of 160 Mb. To run queries I use MySQL Workbench.

Following code runs in 0.015s

```
SELECT *
FROM employees INNER JOIN salaries ON employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no
```

The similar code with GROUP BY added runs for 15.0s

```
SELECT AVG(salary), gender
FROM employees INNER JOIN salaries ON employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no
GROUP BY gender
```

I checked the execution plan for both queries and found that in both cases query cost is similar and is about 600k. I should add that the employee table has 300K rows and the salary table is about 3M rows.

Can anyone suggest a reason why the difference in the execution time is soo huge? I need this explanation to understand the way SQL works better.

Problem solution: As I found due to comments and answers the problem was related to me not noticing that in the case of the first query my IDE was limiting result to 1000 rows. That's how I got 0.015s. In reality, it takes 10.0s to make a join in my case. If the index for gender is created (indices for employees.emp_no and salaries.emp_no already exist in this DB) it takes 10.0s to make join and group by. Without index for gender second query takes 18.0s.

Comment: Thank you for correction. The title should say GROUP BY.

Comment: You should tell us what your objectives are in the two queries.  They are not the same thing, and also your `GROUP BY` query is using a fairly invalid syntax which for various reasons MySQL supports.  Maybe sample data would also be warranted here.

Comment: Why are you selecting **all** columns yet only group by *gender* with no aggregation function (`SUM`, `COUNT`, `AVG`, etc.). What is your intended goal? It is an unfortunate disservice MySQL supports these invalid aggregate queries especially for new comers to SQL. In MySQL 8 [`ONLY FULL GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) is set on by default which would raise an error for your 2nd unclear query.

Comment: The goal of the second query is to join the employee and the salary table to find the average salary per gender later on.

Comment: "The goal of the second query is to join the employee and the salary table to find the average salary per gender later on." later on?  SQL supports `AVG()` function..

Comment: I modified the second query to make it purpose clear.

Comment: @xevepisis - Did you re-time with that actual query or the previous edited out version? Do you have an index on *emp_no* in both tables? If so, I cannot see why that simple aggregate query can yield that much higher than its unit level version. Please post the `EXPLAIN` result.

Comment: I did rerun second query with SELECT AVG.... it takes 16.5s now. Will post visual explain in a moment. Though I mentioned that query cost from that explain is the same for first and second queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EXPLAIN for the first query shows that it does a table-scan (`type=ALL`) of 300K rows from `employees`, and for each one, does a partial primary key (`type=ref`) lookup to 1 row (estimated) in `salaries`.

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM employees 
  INNER JOIN salaries ON employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no;
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+--------+-------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                        | rows   | Extra |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+--------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | employees | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                       | 299113 | NULL  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | salaries  | ref  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | employees.employees.emp_no |      1 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+--------+-------+
```

The EXPLAIN for the second query (actually a sensible query to compute AVG() as you mentioned in your comment) shows something additional:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT employees.gender, AVG(salary) FROM employees 
  INNER JOIN salaries ON employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no 
  GROUP BY employees.gender;
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                        | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | employees | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                       | 299113 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | salaries  | ref  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | employees.employees.emp_no |      1 | NULL                            |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

See the `Using temporary; Using filesort` in the Extra field? That means that the query has to build a temp table to accumulate the AVG() results per group. It has to use a temp table because MySQL can't know that it will scan all the rows for each gender together, so it must assume it will need to maintain running totals independently as it scans rows. It doesn't seem like that would be a big problem to track two (in this case) gender totals, but suppose it were postal code or something like that?

Creating a temp table is a pretty expensive operation. It means *writing* data, not only reading it as the first query does.

If we could make an index that orders by gender, then MySQL's optimizer would know it can scan all those rows with the same gender together. So it can calculate the running total of one gender at a time, then once it's done scanning one gender, calculate the AVG(salary) and then be guaranteed no further rows for that gender will be scanned. Therefore it can skip building a temp table.

This index helps:

```
mysql> alter table employees add index (gender, emp_no);
```

Now the EXPLAIN of the same query shows that it will do an index scan (`type=index`) which visits the same number of entries, but it'll scan in a more helpful order for the calculation of the aggregate AVG().

Same query, but no `Using temporary` note:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT employees.gender, AVG(salary) FROM employees 
  INNER JOIN salaries ON employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no 
  GROUP BY employees.gender;
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys  | key     | key_len | ref                        | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | employees | index | PRIMARY,gender | gender  | 5       | NULL                       | 299113 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | salaries  | ref   | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY | 4       | employees.employees.emp_no |      1 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+--------+-------------+
```

And executing this query is a lot faster:

```
+--------+-------------+
| gender | AVG(salary) |
+--------+-------------+
| M      |  63838.1769 |
| F      |  63769.6032 |
+--------+-------------+
2 rows in set (1.06 sec)
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the non-composite index query version really runs at 15 secs? Or as GordonLinoff mentions, the unit level query runs at 0.015 secs? OP made an edit in his/her original post but may not have adjusted timings.

Comment: Okay I tried executing with `IGNORE INDEX(gender)` and it runs in 2.70 sec. on my Macbook. The OP must have a pretty old or underpowered computer.

Comment: The first `SELECT *` query with no GROUP BY executes in 1.5 sec. on my Macbook. I don't know how the OP is getting 300K rows returned in 0.015 sec., unless they're just miscalculating that time by a factor of 100.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Apparently, MySQL Workbench automatically adds LIMIT 0, 1000 to query that is executed. This explains how I got 0.015s.

Comment: Aha — so instead of returning 300,000 rows, it returns only 1,000. That's why it runs in two orders of magnitude faster than in my test.

Comment: It was first time me using this IDE that led to me confusing you all. I feel bad : )
However, because of it, I learned how to understand "expain" table due to your answer and how to use indices to gain performance. Thank you.

Comment: +1 this answer is better than mine because it actually demonstrates what is going on, while mine was based on documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The addition of the GROUP BY clause could easily explain the big performance drop that you are seeing.

From [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html) :

> The most general way to satisfy a GROUP BY clause is to scan the whole table and create a new temporary table where all rows from each group are consecutive, and then use this temporary table to discover groups and apply aggregate functions (if any).

The additional cost incurred by the grouping process can be very expensive. Also, grouping happens even if no aggregate function is used.

If you don’t need an aggregate function, don’t group. If you do, ensure that you have a single index that references all grouped columns, as suggested by the documentation :

> In some cases, MySQL is able to do much better than that and avoid creation of temporary tables by using index access.

PS : please note that « SELECT * ... GROUP BY »-like statements are not supported since MySQL 5.7.5 (unless you turn off option ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY)

Comment: I feel (not sure) that join and group by operations both have O(NM) complexity where N and M are sizes of employee and salary table. However, join takes 0.015s when group by 15s. So my question is about a possible reason for such a huge difference when complexities and query plan costs are very similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is another reason as well as what GMB points out.  Basically, you are probably looking at the timing of the first query until it returns the *first* row.  I doubt it is returning *all* the rows in 0.015 seconds.

The second query with the `GROUP BY` needs to process *all* the data to derive the results.

If you added an `ORDER BY` (which requires processing all the data) to the first query, then you would see a similar performance drop.